# Parse JSON and loop through it with PHP

Tags: php, json

My problem is loading a JSON file into my php page. With XML / RSS I don't have problems and also in javascript I succeeded, but for this school project I need to load JSON data in PHP.

```
{"tvshows":[
      {
         "showname":"Parenthood ",
         "date":"2014-12-28",
         "fullTitle":"Parenthood (2010) 2x10 \"Happy Thanksgiving \"",
         "img":"http:\/\/zapp.trakt.us\/images\/episodes\/117-2-10.jpg?4"
      },
      {
         "showname":"Parenthood ",
         "date":"2014-12-28",
         "fullTitle":"Parenthood (2010) 2x11 \"Damage Control\"",
         "img":"http:\/\/zapp.trakt.us\/images\/episodes\/117-2-11.jpg?4"
      },
      {
         "showname":"Benched ",
         "date":"2014-12-27",
         "fullTitle":"Benched 1x09 \"A New Development\"",
         "img":"http:\/\/zapp.trakt.us\/images\/episodes\/33221-1-9.jpg?3"
      }
   ]
}
```

When I use this php code doesn't see an output:

```
$string = file_get_contents("url");
$json = json_decode($string, true);

print_r($json);
```

After that I want to walk through the tv shows and show the showname values. How should I do that?

Comment: kan you show us var_dump($string) to make sure its valid json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($json["tvshows"] as $key=>$val){
    echo $key."-".$val["showname"]."<br/>";
}
```